# GAE: New Google Account interface

Tags: google-app-engine, user-interface, user-experience, user-registration

I'm using Google's user api on Google App Engine for authentification. As nearly everyone have a Google Account and api is easy to implement, that solution is convenient.

The problem is, though, with user who do not have a Google Account (or have no idea what a Google Account is). Where the api provides a nice interface to log in/log out and redirect immediately and easily to the app, nothing is said to developers about potential new users.

So here are a couple of things worth noticing:

1. Google' new Google Account page (https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount) is pretty straightforward, but not convenient at all for new users of a GAE app: no mention of anything not Google (users who don't really know what authentification is won't have any clue of why they need to open an account with Google), dead end (won't lead anywhere in the end), ugly.
2. GAE Log In screen includes a link to the New Google Account page. This link is of the form:

> https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F_ah%2Flogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fprofile%2F&service=ah&ltmpl=gm&sig=0aa0a000aa000a00000aa0000a000aa

(Where example.com is the return url provided to the API). Great! But the situation is in no way different than it was: still a dead end, still no mention of any non-Google app, still ugly).

So, I'm asking, is there any imaginative way to provide a nicer interface for new users? Have anyone have ideas of how to present the process to the new users (a video for how to create a new account? some kind of tutorial page? etc.)? Just trying to think outside of the technical box here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the various authentication options you can check out the [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html#Authentication_Options) or Python docs on OpenID (http://openid.net/)
Basically this allows supporting authentication by different agents, which includes Google accounts or even your own GAE application's custom implementation.

Furthermore you can check out [User Experience summary for Federated Login](http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/summary) for more information regarding UX considerations and best practices - with user authentication.

Comment: That still doesn't resolve the problem: 1. users will still have to create an account somewhere else (Google for example). Yes, offering more than one choice reduces the amount of users in such a scenario. But the problem is still there: how to explain and guide users through the creation of an account. 2. App Engine federated login is still experimental and making the transition extremely painful. Also, user experience using the federated interface login page offered by google and other providers is even worst than the one of app engine's original users api.

Comment: Regarding 1. most users already do have some account with another provider so you will probably address most users - however the only way to control the signup process is to own it. So you can setup your own signup system and plug it into the existing openid support.
As to 2. although the support for OpenID is "experimental" the transition is not painful at all code-wise as you use the same User service: [http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html)