# Google Accounts customization in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-account

Well, this question is regarding the authentication system of an app in GAE. I've read several posts and found out the best way to manage the user authentication stuff is using the Google Accounts service. I've read several suggestion ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972788/gae-new-google-account-interface) is one of them) but they don't really give a solution to the problem.

Here is what I want to do: I am going to use the Google Accounts service and I want to know if there is a way to change the login and create account page, so that I don not have to redirect the user to the Google Sign-in form, but rather redirect the user to my own login form and then forward those data to Google Servers. I would like to do the same exact thing with the register form. In conclusion I need that the user feels she is using the login of my application, but is really using the Google Accounts service.

Here is an example of something I want to do: [This](http://login.unal.edu.co/sso/auth.htm) webpage uses Google Accounts Service, but the login form, is a custom form that then (I imagine) forwards the data to Google Servers and then logs the user in.

Comment: I don't think you really should do this; people shouldn't be typing their Google account credentials into a non-Google-hosted form. (Your language even sounds a bit like phishing "the user feels she is using the login of my application, but is really using the Google Accounts service".)This will probably also break Google's two-factor authentication, etc.

Comment: I understand. So, your suggestion is to roll my own authentication system? Or go for another option like using OpenID or OAuth.

Comment: If using Google's existing system isn't acceptable, you probably should roll your own with OAuth or OpenID, yeah. App Engine does have experimental "built-in" support for OpenID-based logins: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid. You could, I'm sure, find lots of Python/Java OAuth integrations as well.